# DevExpress Show RepositoryItemMemoExEdit when PropertyGrid is ReadOnly

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, propertygrid

Is there any way to show a RepositoryItemMemoEx when the propertyGrid (DevExpress) is in ReadOnly mode. I want the repository to be showed so the user can see the text but no edit.

The standard behaviour is a little weird because if the editor is not shown, you cannot read the text on it. I already checked Google with no result, maybe there is some kind of trick or workaround.

I'm using the winforms controls.

thanks,

Comment: The thing has Edit in its name. So that its usefulness is limited when set readonly shouldn't be a surprise to you ;) Why use an editor in the first place? I don't see a need if you just want to show text?

Comment: The reason is that text can be large enough to consider showing it in a more bigger control than the standard propertyGrid row. This approach works fine when the propertyGrid is not readonly but has a lack when not (yo cannot show the editor anyway)

Comment: Then you can't set the view or column to readonly. But you can set the repository item to readonly.

Comment: I'm on an older version of the controls but knewer versions should have a AllowDropDownWhenReadOnly property. At least its mentioned in the Devexpress KB that it has been added with the 2011 2.5 release.

Comment: True, but AllowDropDownWhenReadOnly = true does not work I think because of "A DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean value that specifies if an editor's dropdown can be displayed in the read-only state." And in my situation the editor is not readonly, is the propertyGrid. Show the propertyGrid is inhibiting the editor. :(

Comment: Then the workaround would be making the view editable but setting all columns to readonly besides the one with the MemoExEdit. Then you should set the RepositoryItem to ReadOnly. Your view wouldn't be editable at all but you get the dropdown.

Comment: @danijepg: Hi, were you able to figure out  a solution for this. Show the RepositoryItemMemoEx even when it is read only.

Comment: @user575219: No, I did no further investigation but someaone told me it's possible, sorry I can't help you